# making one option disabled after selecting

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried to bind those two code ideas together but it isn't working.

I want to disable the first option from being selectable after a selection has been made.

[This is the behavior I'm wanting](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/dq97z/57/); the first option is disabled after a selection is made.

And [this is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/dq97z/54/) where I want the first option disabled when a subsequent element is picked.

Comment: Your description is very hard to follow, any chance you could restate the effect you want?

Comment: You didn't have a `<p>` element to attach things to and the submit feature isn't going to operate well in jsfiddle. Here is a potentially cleaned up version of your question. What are you wanting to occur here? http://jsfiddle.net/dq97z/62/

Comment: the <p> i need somewhere else , and ur code didnt disapear the (select one )

Comment: You want "select one" as an option to be removed from the select?

Comment: not removed but disabled as in the exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this answers your inquiry:

http://jsfiddle.net/dq97z/66/

Inside of `displayVals` I executed the following:

```
if ($("#menucompare").prop("selectedIndex") !== "0") {
    // Within the select (you could be more specific) find
    // the first (direct descendant) option value and 
    // disable it to make it unselectable
    $("select > option:first").prop("disabled", "disabled")
}
```

This segment finds out what the selected index of your select menu is and if the user has selected something other than the initial one (0), it sets the first option to be disabled.

**Update**: http://jsfiddle.net/dq97z/72/

Changed `attr()` to `prop()` when disabling per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and @silkster's advice. Thanks

Also, if you don't want the option selectable at the beginning, you could even do it without an if statement as [seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/dq97z/75/).

```
function displayVals() {
    var singleValues = $("select option:selected").text();
    ....
    $("select > option:first").prop("disabled", "disabled")
}
```

The disabling happens after the DOM is loaded (with the first one *not* disabled) so the select can still have 'Please select' selected. Whoah...that's a lot of "select"s.

If you want to leave the if statement there (which means 'select one' is selectable until another is actually selected), your if statement would need to be like this:

```
if ($("#menucompare").prop("selectedIndex") !== 0) // with no quotes around zero
```

Comment: u have removed this ` //$("#aform").submit();  ` ?

Comment: Yes; if you uncomment that, you'll see why. It probably would be fine with your site (wherever you are implementing the form to actually do something) but the submit is going to fail in jsfiddle

Comment: You should use .prop() instead of .attr() to set 'disabled'

Comment: and plus , u make it better, koz the first option appears but not selectable , very nice

Comment: gosto, that's actually an accident. selectedIndex is 0 not "0" when `displayVals` gets called on `ready`. Therefore, the disabling happens immediately after the document is loaded. You get the same behavior [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/dq97z/75/). Go figure :-)

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED ANSWER]

http://jsfiddle.net/N9JEx/2/

```
function displayVals() {
    var singleValues = $("select option:selected").text();
    if (!isNaN(singleValues )) {
        $("#hiddenselect").val(singleValues);
        $("<p></p>").html("Percent of : &nbsp" + singleValues).appendTo('body');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        displayVals();
        if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {
            var option = $('option:selected', this);
            option.prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: this is the code example i gave , i want to make the first option (Select one) disabled like in the exemple , make it in my code here http://jsfiddle.net/dq97z/54/

Comment: No, I edited the code so only the select list is disabled.  this.disabled = true;

Comment: my answer is updated.  Don't submit the form on JSFiddle.  Looks like you're trying to mix PHP into it. As far as I know, that won't work there.

Comment: u have disabled the option selected , its not that what i want , i want desable the first option whe others are selected , anyway its solved by `WeeTrain` above , thx for helping +1